# Explanation of some simple details on total orthonormal sets.

Tags: functional-analysis

Studying I came across these two statements that the book considers self-evident, but to me they are not. Could you explain me why? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Actually your question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116911/difference-between-total-orthonormal-set-and-basis), but I will leave my answer for now, since it contains a bit more information

Answer (score 2):

Basis in the sense of algebra, in the context of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces usually called a Hamel basis, means that every element of the space can be written as a **finite** linear combination of elements within this basis.That is not necessarily the case for a total orthonormal set, also called Hilbert basis, in fact for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces a Hamel basis is always uncountable, as a consequence of a Hilbert space being complete and Baire´s category theorem, while for an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space there exists a countable total orthonormal set.

Comment: [Here](https://math.mit.edu/~lguth/Math103/pset4.pdf) are the definitions and some exercises.